# Make variations in wp-commerce compulsory

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I am trying to make a clothes store for my clothing label using wp-commerce.
I have set the variations for shirt sizes and they are working ok except that when someone doesn't choose a size it adds the shirt to the cart at 0 cost.
I am pretty new to php and would like to make it so that it is compulsory to select a size when you do this.

Here is the site url http://ownc.co.nz/shop/t-shirts/in-a-class-of-our-own/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making one of the buttons checked with jQuery to fix this

```
$('input.sizeBtn').eq(2).prop('checked', true).parent().addClass('selected');
```